# How do I stop Preston Garvey from being hostile to me?

Tags: fallout-4

I pickpocketed someone in the group and now he is trying to kill me. He won't die. How do I make him non-hostile?

Answer (score 10):

When you get someone (or even an entire settlement/town) angry at you, you need to give him some time to cool off.

Get away from that location and sleep/wait in a safe spot for at least 48 hours.

Once you've been away for at least two in-game days you can come back safely. He will have forgotten everything about your offenses by then and be friendly once again.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not mind a little lost game time you can use the "load" function to go back to a time before you pickpocketed him. So just load an earlier save. This also works well for times when you fall into a hole or water where you cannot get out or just feel you make a mistake that you would like to correct.

Comment: Unassociated to the original question, but when you're stuck (unable to physically get out of somewhere) you can often still just fast travel away. This way you don't loose any progress. :)